# How to apply gradient at back of TableView Controller?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift4

I have a UITableViewController in the storyboard. I want to apply a gradient on back of the table. I used this code to apply the gradient on other view's but in case of table view controller the gradient just seems to overlay on the tableview itself.

I have tried giving gradient to tableView instead of view but it works the same way.

```swift
  //MARK:gradient and orientation
    func applyGradient()
    {

        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.frame = self.view.bounds
        gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.purple.cgColor,UIColor.red.cgColor]
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1)
        self.view.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
    }
    //Gradient
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        applyGradient()
    }
```

Comment: Add gradient in tableview background View.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert the gradient's layer to a `UIView` and assign it as the `backgroundView` of your `tableView`:-

```
let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
gradientLayer.frame = yourTableView.bounds
gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.purple.cgColor,UIColor.red.cgColor]
gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1)

let backgroundView = UIView(frame: yourTableView.bounds)    
backgroundView.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)

yourTableView.backgroundView = backgroundView
```

Also make sure that your cells are `.clear` in colour

Comment: anytime mate :-)

Comment: Thanks..I added this in tableview and it worked. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of ways to obtain a gradient background for UITableView.
The key point is to utilize `CAGradientLayer` class.

## CAGradientLayer

`CAGradientLayer` is a subclass of `CALayer`. As you might know, `CALayer` is the backing block of `UIView` instances and do the basic rendering. `CAGradientLayer` is for gradient effects.

## Change backing layer class type of UIView or UIView Subclasses

You can change the class type for backing layer of UIView or it's subclasses.
To achieve this, you have to override `layerClass` property of the UIView or it's subclass.

```swift
class GradientTableView: UITableView {

    // Note this line of code
    override class var layerClass: AnyClass { return CAGradientLayer.self } 

    // More codes ...  
}
```

## Access the layer as CAGradientLayer

Since you have the backing layer class to `CAGradientLayer`, your UIView or subclass's `.layer` is now an instance of `CAGradientLayer`. You can safely force typecast `.layer` into it.

```swift
class GradientTableView: UITableView {

    override class var layerClass: AnyClass { return CAGradientLayer.self } 

    // Note this line of code
    var gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer { return self.layer as! CAGradientLayer }

    // More codes ...  
}
```

## Make some ways to access `gradientLayer`

`CAGradientLayer` has it's own properties to make it appear gradient. Make it easily accessible from outside of your UIView class.

**Following is the full working code of GradientTableView**

```swift
@IBDesignable
class GradientTableView: UITableView {

    /*
     * You can change the type of backing layer through this override.
     */
    override class var layerClass: AnyClass {
        return CAGradientLayer.self
    }

    /*
     * After overriden layerClass, your `layer` is now an instance of CAGradientLayer.
     *
     * You can safely force typecast your `layer` object as CAGradientLayer.
     */
    private var gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer! { return self.layer as? CAGradientLayer }


    // MARK:- CAGradientLayer helpers.
    @IBInspectable private var startColor: UIColor = .white {
        didSet { gradientColors = [startColor, endColor] }
    }

    @IBInspectable private var endColor: UIColor = .white {
        didSet { gradientColors = [startColor, endColor] }
    }


    var gradientColors: [UIColor] = [] {
        didSet { gradientLayer.colors = gradientColors.map{ $0.cgColor } }
    }

    /// Starting point for gradient color.
    @IBInspectable var gradientStartPoint: CGPoint {
        set { gradientLayer.startPoint = newValue }
        get { return gradientLayer.startPoint }
    }

    /// Ending point for gradient color.
    @IBInspectable var gradientEndPoint: CGPoint {
        set { gradientLayer.endPoint = newValue }
        get { return gradientLayer.endPoint }
    }
}
```

## Change your UITableView to GradientTableView through Identity Inspector in storyboard.

[image: Change UITableView to GradientTableView]

## Play with some values from storyboard.

[image: Play with some values from storyboard]

## And you get a neat Gradient background of UITableView.

[image]